# Get all Sitecore users with custom property

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a Sitecore solution that has around 800,000 users across two Sitecore domains.

I need to export all the users with one custom property.

I started with this code.....

```
var getAllUsers = UserManager.GetUsers();
var file = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("AllUsersFile", @"C:\AllUsers.txt");

using (System.IO.StreamWriter datafile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file))
{
    datafile.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "email", "domain", "subscribed");

    foreach (var user in getAllUsers)
    {
        var dn = user.Domain.Name;
        if (dn == "domain1" || dn == "domain2")
        {
            var profile = (UserProfile)user.Profile;
            var email = profile.Email;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            {
                var domain = user.Domain;
                var subscribed = profile.GetCustomProperty(Settings.Account.SubscribedToNewsletter).ToBool();

                datafile.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", email, domain, subscribed ? "1" : "0");
            }
        }
    }
}

var response = new StringBuilder();
response.AppendLine("Done.");
SheerResponse.Alert(response.ToString());
```

After this running for 30 hours it had exported 302,500 then died (no error, it just stopped).  I tried to start it again from where it left off but that is just as slow.

I read  [this](https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/get-all-sitecore-users-by-domain/) article..

So changed the code...

```
List<string> domainsList = new List<string> {"domain1", "domain2"};
var file = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("AllUsersFile", @"C:\AllUsers.txt");

using (System.IO.StreamWriter datafile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file))
{
    datafile.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "email", "domain", "subscribed");
    foreach (string dname in domainsList)
    {
        List<User> getAllUsers = Domain.GetDomain(dname).GetUsers().ToList();
        foreach (User user in getAllUsers)
        {
            var dn = user.Domain.Name;

            var profile = (UserProfile)user.Profile;
            var email = profile.Email;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            {
                var subscribed = profile.GetCustomProperty(Settings.Account.SubscribedToNewsletter).ToBool();
                datafile.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", email, dn, subscribed ? "1" : "0");
            }
        }
    }
}

var response = new StringBuilder();
response.AppendLine("Done.");
SheerResponse.Alert(response.ToString());
```

Its now been running for 6 hours and it still hasn't returned the list of users from the first domain let alone started to get the custom property for each.

Should I expect it to take so long?  Is there another way I can do this that wont take so long?

Comment: It will take very long. You should take a look at this question here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/get-user-by-custom-property

Comment: Which membership provider do you use? You can make te exports outside Sitecore in SQL. Another way is to work with paging same as the user manager inside sitecore works, take x user process and take the next. May not be faster, but you can pause and pick up where you left off.

Comment: @JanBluemink Im using ASP.NET Membership.  I can get most of what I need straight from the SQL tables but I cant get the custom property I need.  From what I can see I need to load the user and and use `user.Profile.GetCustomPropery` to get this.  I will look at paging, like you say at least I will be able to start off from where it stopped.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this problem, this is how I got round it in the end.

I took a back up of the live databases and restored them as temporary databases.  While using these databases I updated my code to delete the user once I had the detail I was after.  The more users that got deleted the faster it ran.  As I said in the question the first 300K took 30 hours but after these were deleted the next 100K took 1 hour.

Not a great solution but it was a one off data extract.